# Change feather icon in JS

Tags: jquery, feathericons

I am using feathericons and I am looking to simply change the `data-feather` attribute on click of an icon with id `powerOn`.  It's a simple power button.

I tried:

```
const powerOn = $('#powerOn');
powerOn.attr('data-feather', 'stop-circle');
```

but that doesn't work.  I also see the API has a `replace()` function, but don't quite understand how to apply it in this case.

I am looking to switch the icon back to it's initial state after the button is clicked again as in:

```
powerOn.attr('data-feather', 'power');
```

New to JS and JQuery and the [library](https://github.com/feathericons/feather) .

Here is my HTML:

```
<button id="connectId"
        onclick="connect()"
        class="btn btn-sm btn-success"><i id="powerOn" data-feather="power"></i> Power On</button>
```

**Update**: corrected typo in question to include hashtag for element ID.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
const powerOn = $('#powerOn');
powerOn.replaceWith(feather.icons['stop-circle'].toSvg());
```

Comment: Nice!  Any idea why `attr()` doesn't work in this case?  Is it because I would need to handle the SVG manipulation directly?

Comment: I think it is because, even though the attribute is changed, the content of the SVG is not modified

Answer (score 4):

I needed to replace the entire html to have the toggle functionality as in:

```
const connectId = $('#connectId');
connectId.html(feather.icons['power'].toSvg() + ' Power On');
```

and

`connectid.html(feather.icons['stop-circle'].toSvg() + ' Power Off');`

Using just `powerOn.replaceWith` will remove the `<i>` tag, so the icon will not always appear.

Comment: Vanilla JS would be -> `connectId.innerHTML = feather.icons['stop-circle'].toSvg();`

Answer (score 0):

Change attribute with `jQuery` then do a clean `feather.replace()`